# Reverse proxy - route to the same machine based on IP

Tags: load-balancing, reverse-proxy

Say I have a load balancer (Nginx or another, it doesn't matter) and I want it to route to a machine based on IP. The IP is not known at configuration time. So, for example, I have a load balancer in front of machines m1 and m2. A request comes from IP10 and it gets routed to m1, all subsequent requests from IP10 also get routed to m1. Another request comes from IP11 and it gets routed to m2, all subsequent requests from IP11 also get routed to m2.

Is this possible, if so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description I understand that you don't have a specific requirement for where the first request from a specific IP will be routed as long as all the subsequent requests will follow the same route.

If that's the case the action you want to perform is a load balancing method called *session stickiness* or *persistent session*.

In nginx you can achieve that with the following configuration:

```
http {
    upstream mybackend {
        ip_hash;
        server m1.ltd;
        server m2.ltd;
     }

     server {
         listen 80;

         location / {
             proxy_pass http://mybackend;
         }
     }
}
```

Here is the link to the specific [nginx docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/load_balancing.html#nginx_load_balancing_with_ip_hash).

Comment: Thanks! Is it also possible to limit the number of clients per servers? So, for example, if there are three servers and each is allowed five client IPs when the 16th IP is seen by the load balancer it fails that IP? This also requires "expiring" client IPs after a timeout I suppose.

Comment: Exactly that functionality you describe is part of [nginx+](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/load-balancer/#maxconns) (commercial). Usually you can achieve similar func by knowing how many requests or connections your backend can handle and size it properly in order not to fail. Also if you have servers with different resources you can use the weight method.